# SonarQube Plugin Extension Using Plexus / IoC

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube, plexus

I am attempting to write an extension to the SonarQube checkstyle plugin. I would like to use dependency injection to wire required dependencies. From what I can see (documentation seems to be lacking) SonarQube uses plexus as its IoC container. In my custom plugin I have added the necessary dependencies to generate a plexus components file (confirmed packaged in the plugin jar at "/META-INF/plexus/components.xml"). However when I start the server it issues an error stating dependencies can't be found:

```
org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException:
foo.SonarCheckstyleRuleRepository has unsatisfied dependency 'interface foo.MyInterface'
for constructor 'public foo.SonarCheckstyleRuleRepository(
    foo.MyInterface,foo.DifferentInterface)'...
```

Is there additional configuration required in the plugin (outside of the components.xml) to register the components within the SonarQube server? Do I need to package the plexus classworlds library with the plugin? Is there something additional required to integrate with "pico container"?

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube does not use Plexus, it uses [PicoContainer](http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/).

Comment: Is there documentation or tutorials how to properly leverage the PicoContainer in the context of writing custom sonarqube plugins?

Comment: Everything we have is available at http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/extension-guide.html. Or you can also read the source code of our many open-source plugins: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/